# Conditional a href in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am rendering a list of store titles in VueJS, some of them have a url property, some of them don't. If the title has a url, I want to add a a href property:

```
<div v-for="(store, index) in stores">
  <span v-if="store.link"><a :href="store.link" target="_blank">{{ store.title }}</a></span>
  <span v-else="store.link">{{ store.title }}</span>
</div>
```

This works, but the code looks duplicated. Is there anyway to simplify the code further?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use component tag:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      stores: [
        {title:'product1',link:'/products/222'},
        {title:'product2'},
        {title:'product3',link:'/products/333'},
        {title:'product4'}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(store, index) in stores">
    <component :is="store.link?'a':'span'" :href="store.link || ''" target="_blank">{{store.title}}
    </component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Such a wonderful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'd remove the first `span` element, as it's not necessary. Also, the `v-else` does not need the conditional statement (it's not [`v-else-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else-if)):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stores: [
      { link: 'foo', title: 'foo-text' },
      { title: 'bar-text' } 
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(store, index) in stores" :key="index">
    <a v-if="store.link" :href="store.link" target="_blank">{{ store.title }}</a>
    <span v-else>{{ store.title }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic arguments in vue3
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#dynamic-arguments

```
<a v-bind:[attributeName]="url"> ... </a>
```

or binding an object of attributes

```
<div v-bind="{ id: someProp, 'other-attr': otherProp }"></div>
```